# Seek, move front back in a file cut and paste

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, text-files

I need to do the following things for a text file..and insert the seeked words to a excel please give me some tips:

Seek the letter sequence anywhere in the file "stg-" take the first two characters from where it is searched ... eg if  the sentence has abc-stg-c5-sfdsdf   then it should take c5 and this c5 should insert in the first column first row of the excel file.

Comment: Ok, this question is too broad to answer. It is actually several questions 1) How to find text in a file. 2) How to write values to excel. You'll find both of these questions have already been asked and answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first impression is that the search is best conducted by using a [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28VS.80%29.aspx).

You don't say if you have an open instance of Excel (i.e. you can do the insert using [Excel automation](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/ExcelAutomation01052007080910AM/ExcelAutomation.aspx)), or if you want to write it directly into an Excel compatible file - in which case you may find it simplest to write a comma-delimited file.

Does this help?